# How did all the Yuuzhan Vong fit on Zonoma Sekot?

Tags: star-wars, yuuzhan-vong

At the end of the New Jedi Order series of novels, it seems that the entire Yuuzhan Vong population was rehabilitated as settlers on Zonoma Sekot. But the Yuuzhan Vong population formerly occupied an entire galaxy, and hoped to occupy the Galaxy Far Far Away. How did they all fit on one planet?

Comment: The invading force was not as large as they were when they occupied an entire galaxy

Answer (score 3):

First at the end of LOF many(most) of the YV have been destroyed.

Second through their bio-forms the Vong were able to quickly overwhelm and occupy a planet then manage it with a relativity low number of Vong when compared to Republic or Imperial occupation forces.

Finally Zonoma Sekot was described as being a very large planet several times the size of Coruscant.